# How to start WireGuard client without sudo privileges?

Tags: debian, vpn, remote-desktop, sudo, wireguard

I am desperately trying to set up a "sudoless" way to start a WireGuard tunnel. The user has no elevated rights on Debian 12 Bookworm.

The user needs a simple way to get access to a terminal server with `xfreerdp`. The user will anyway have to use password when he connects to the terminal server over VPN so that requesting another password for `wg-quick` is redundant, I think. (The user needs a password for logging in Linux and a second  password to log in to the terminal server).

I created a desktop icon for the user which starts the following command:

```
wg-quick up user ; xfreerdp <all-the-stuff-for-logging-in-at-the remote server> ; wg-quick down user
```

So that when RDP session is finished, VPN will be down automatically. I put following line at the end of `/etc/sudoers` using visudo:

```
user ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/wg-quick
```

The desktop starter does nothing. If I run the command in a terminal it keeps asking for password for `wg-quick`.

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Quick answer :

**No**, you can not without `sudo` privileges for the user.

#### Longer answer (and solution to not being blocked) :

You can't avoid using `sudo` for that, `wg-quick` needs root privileges to work. **However**, as you only authorized one command `wg-quick` in the `/etc/sudoers`, there is no security risk to use `sudo`. The user won't be able to run another command than `wg-quick` (no elevated privileges).

What you did is almost good, you just forgot one essential element : the `sudo` before `wg-quick` commands. Here the command that should works :

```
sudo wg-quick up user ; xfreerdp <all-the-stuff-for-logging-in-at-the remote server> ; sudo wg-quick down user
```

Without this `sudo`, the `/etc/sudoers` won't apply the rule. This is logic. You need it before run the allowed commands.

(I just tested on a Debian based distribution to confirm).

Comment: The title of this question explicitly states: “How to start WireGuard client without sudo privileges?” How does suggesting using `sudo` help? Would `sudo` work because of the line for `wg-quick` in `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: Yes, right. I added one sentence at the beginning to explain.

Comment: So the answer is no answer because the original poster states: “The user has no elevated rights on Debian 12 Bookworm.” If they need to use `sudo` but don’t have elevated rights then that won’t work?

Comment: My answer does not really answer to the question but it provides a solution to the user's blocking. Do I need to modify something ?

Comment: Perhaps clearly state, no it cannot be done. Unless `sudo` can be run without elevated rights?

Comment: I agree. Is it fine now ?

Comment: It seems good to me now!

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the clarification !

Comment: This is a way, but absolutely not a safe one depending on how you set `sudoers`, if you set the rule using the command name only, a simple `cp /usr/bin/rm /tmp/wg-quick; sudo wg-quick -rf /*` would work

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The `sudoers` entry in the original question explicitl points to `/usr/bin/wg-quick` so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. There is one point remaining to be corrected - a desktop starter will not accept a script to run. I had to put the command sequence in a file and make it executable to have a starter icon working. Thank you again.